# Progress 4GL: Labelling a field from a variable

Tags: progress-4gl

I am having trouble labelling a field(s) on a frame. The number of fields and the required labels are determined at run-time.

the required labels are stored in char array:

```
w-indarray[]
```

I am using the following loop to add the required fields to the frame

```
do i = 1 to w-nooff:                               
form w-sstrings[i] with frame f1.     
w-sstrings[i]:label in frame f1 = w-indarray[i].
end.
```

But I get an error:

```
Widget array-element requires constant subscript.
```

I have googled but the only occurrence looks slightly different and I'm not sure if the solution is applicable. http://www.mofeel.net/258-comp-databases-progress/5295a6889.aspx

I am assuming that being able to reference the elements of w-indarray[] as literals would resolve this as i could just do:

```
form w-sstrings[i] label "abc" with frame f1.
```

is there any way of referencing the elements of the w-indarray[] as literals that I am missing?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using static numbers for the extent by getting all widget handles and modifying their labels. It works but it's kind of a lot code to do something that really should be easier.

Something like this:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cLabel       AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO EXTENT 10 INIT ["One","Two","three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten"].
DEFINE VARIABLE cField       AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO EXTENT 10.
DEFINE VARIABLE hFieldGroup  AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hFirstWidget AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iExtent      AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iLoop        AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

DEFINE FRAME f1 WITH SIDE-LABELS 1 COLUMN.

DISPLAY 
    cField
    WITH FRAME f1.
/* Static will be done like this
Commenting out this 
ASSIGN                                   
    cField[1]:LABEL  = cLabel[1]
    cField[2]:LABEL  = cLabel[2]
    cField[3]:LABEL  = cLabel[3]
    cField[4]:LABEL  = cLabel[4]
    cField[5]:LABEL  = cLabel[5]
    cField[6]:LABEL  = cLabel[6]
    cField[7]:LABEL  = cLabel[7]
    cField[8]:LABEL  = cLabel[8]
    cField[9]:LABEL  = cLabel[9]
    cField[10]:LABEL = cLabel[10].
 */


ASSIGN
    hFieldGroup  = FRAME f1:FIRST-CHILD
    hFirstWidget = hFieldGroup:FIRST-CHILD. 

/* Widget-loop. Could really be done prettier... */
REPEAT:
    iLoop = iLoop + 1.

    hFirstWidget =  hFirstWidget:NEXT-SIBLING NO-ERROR.

    IF hFirstwIDGET = ? THEN LEAVE.

    IF hFirstWidget:TYPE = "FILL-IN" THEN DO:
        iExtent = iExtent + 1.
        /* Set dynamic label */
        hFirstWidget:LABEL = cLabel[iExtent].
    END.
END.
```

Comment: Hi Jensd, thanks for the response, i have tested your code and it works for your example, however in my case i do not know how many fields i need in frame until runtime. I have tried setting the extent using "assign extent(cField) = 2" (test example), but it falls over with "Invalid use of indeterminate extents.  Cannot be passed unsubscripted into frames." To resolve this instead of displaying cField i looped around the display statement to display cField[counter variable] but now only the first cField element is displayed in frame. Would you know how to make this work for unknown array size

Comment: Consider putting the labels in a temp-table instead rather than an array. That will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says you need to use a constant in the array instead of a variable. This means you'll need to do a CASE statement to get the functionality you're looking for - like so:

```
CASE i:
WHEN 1 THEN w-sstrings[1]:label in frame f1 = w-indarray[i].
WHEN 2 THEN w-sstrings[2]:label in frame f1 = w-indarray[i].
WHEN 3 THEN w-sstrings[3]:label in frame f1 = w-indarray[i].
WHEN 4 THEN w-sstrings[4]:label in frame f1 = w-indarray[i].
WHEN 5 THEN w-sstrings[5]:label in frame f1 = w-indarray[i].
END CASE.
```

The reason for the constant array element is the compiler can't discern which field the array element corresponds to when you give it a variable designation.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the response. I have added the code suggested directly below the "form w-sstrings[i] with frame f1." line but receive a "could not find w-sstrings in frame f1" error on compilation. I'll try and figure it out but if you have any suggestions i would be grateful. thanks again

Comment: PSC is funny about de-referencing frame fields - the construct above is one way, another is 

FRAME frame-name widget-name:label

Try this and see what happens.

Comment: I think i am misunderstanding the syntax, trying: "frame f1 w-array[1]:label = "test"." gives me a syntax error.